# How to target .net 4.5 with CSharpCodeProvider?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-4.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using CSharpCodeProvider with .net 4.5 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591584/using-csharpcodeprovider-with-net-4-5-beta)

For .net 3.5 I pass v3.5 to CSharpCodeProvider, when I pass v4.5 to CSharpCodeProvider in a v4.5 app I get `InvalidOperationException` "Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found."

Anyone any idea what's going on here, what am I doing wrong?

Code to reproduce . . .

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Console1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var options = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"CompilerVersion", "v4.5"}};
            var cs = new CSharpCodeProvider(options);

            var compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();

            var r = cs.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams , "namespace ns { class program { public static Main(string[] args) { System.Console.WriteLine(\"Hello world\"); } } }");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw that question about th 4.5 beta, and decide to ask this, give  that something may have changed between the beta and final release.

Comment: Did you try using v4.0 to see if it worked with the 4.5 syntax?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is by design, something you can see when you navigate to c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework with Windows Explorer.  Note that you'll only see a subdirectory named v4.0.30319, there is no v4.5 subdirectory.  Or in other words, .NET 4.5 is a true in-place update for version 4.0 and the C# v5 compiler *replaces* the v4 compiler.

You'll need to specify "v4.0".

Comment: Thanks, I assumed it should work the same way as the .net 3.0-3.5 update, but obviously not. Couldn't figure if it was "accidentally" working when targeting v4.0 from 4.5 and something was happening that I was unaware of. Thanks again for a definitive answer.