# `Add-Type` C# 6+ features throwing errors

Tags: c#, powershell, roslyn

I am trying to compile [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) source code in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) by using this command:

```
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblies -TypeDefinition $source
```

But [c#-6.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-6.0) features are not working, for example:

> `Add-Type : c:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\2\d2q5hn5b.0.cs(101) : Unexpected character '$'`

For code:

```
new Problem($"... ({identifier})", node)
```

I am using [powershell-v5.1](/questions/tagged/powershell-v5.1)

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Powershell uses `CodeDomProvider` to compile their assemblies.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) The version provided with the framework just supports C# 5, so no new features are available by default.

However, if you provide another `CodeDomProvider`, you can compile any language, also C#6. [There is a `CodeDomProvider` available for Roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31639602/993547) (the new .NET compiler). You can [download it from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/) and include the assembly using `Add-Type`. Then create an instance of the compiler and pass that in the `-CodeDomProvider` attribute.

Answer (score 7):

To expand upon [Patrick Hoffmans's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40789694), I was a bit uncomfortable about using the reflection method in [unbob's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42537676) as that could potentially break in the future.

I worked out the following `powershell` code instead which uses `.NET` named classes and interfaces:

```bash
#requires -Version 5

# download https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/
# and extract with 7-zip to a location, enter that location on the next line
$DotNetCodeDomLocation = 'C:\Utils\microsoft.codedom.providers.dotnetcompilerplatform'
Add-Type -Path "$DotNetCodeDomLocation\lib\net475\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll"

# using Invoke-Expression moves this class definition to runtime, so it will work after the Add-Type
# and the ps5 class interface implementation will succeed. This uses the public interface ICompilerSettings
# instead of the private class CompilerSettings
Invoke-Expression -Command @"
class RoslynCompilerSettings : Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.ICompilerSettings
{
    [string] get_CompilerFullPath()
    {
        // This path may need to be updated for newer versions
        return "$DotNetCodeDomLocation\tools\Roslyn-4.1.0\csc.exe"
    }
    [int] get_CompilerServerTimeToLive()
    {
        return 10
    }
}
"@

$DotNetCodeDomProvider = [Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider]::new([RoslynCompilerSettings]::new())
```

This can then be used as in the following examples:

- To directly add a type to the `powershell` instance, with assembly reference example (requires the `roslyn` compiler and the above code to be bundled with your script):

  ```
  $addTypeSplat = @{
      TypeDefinition       = $your_source_code_block
      ReferencedAssemblies = @([System.Reflection.Assembly]::GetAssembly([hashtable]).Location)
      CodeDomProvider      = $DotNetCodeDomProvider
  }
  Add-Type @addTypeSplat
  ```
- To compile the code to a `dll` for loading in future/other scripts (only requires the resulting `dll` file to be bundled with your script):

  ```bash
  $DotNetAssemblyParameters = [System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters]::new(
      @([System.Reflection.Assembly]::GetAssembly([hashtable]).Location),
      'path_and_name_for_saved.dll',
      $false
  )

  # you can adjust more compilation settings here if you want, see
  # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters?view=netframework-4.7.2
  $compilationResults = $DotNetCodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
      $DotNetAssemblyParameters,
      $your_source_code_block
  )
  ```

The compiled `dll` can then be used with a simple `Add-Type`:

```
Add-Type -Path 'path_and_name_for_saved.Dll'
```

This allows for you to use the latest `.NET` compiler in `powershell` either inline with your main script if you bundle the `CodeDomProvider` `dll` and the `roslyn` compiler, or you can compile the `C#` code out to a `dll` so it doesn't have to be recompiled each time the script is run, allowing for easier portability and a faster script run time.

Answer (score 1):

When I try Mr. Hoffman's approach, I get the following error:

```
Add-Type : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin\roslyn\csc.exe'.
```

user1676558 [mentions two solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42263416/876993):

1. A [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.BinFix/) that contains a fix for this specific problem
2. A [snippet of C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40311406/876993) that reflects out the offending private field and fixes it

Being a (little league) PowerShell hacker, I came up with my own PowerShellian solution, based on examination of the [source code](https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/1.0.0/Release/.NETFramework,Version=v4.5/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/CSharpCodeProvider.cs):

```
$dncpTypes = Add-Type -Path C:\<path where I put the dll>\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll -PassThru
$dncpTypTab = [ordered]@{}
$dncpTypes | %{$dncpTypTab[$_.Name] = $_}

$compSetCtor    = $dncpTypTab.CompilerSettings.GetConstructor(@([string],[int]))
$compSettings   = $compSetCtor.Invoke(@('C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\csc.exe', 10))
$cscpOtherCtor  = $dncpTypTab.CSharpCodeProvider.GetConstructor('NonPublic,Instance', $null, @($dncpTypTab.ICompilerSettings), $null)
$roslynProvider = $cscpOtherCtor.Invoke($compSettings)
```

Needless to say, there's some discussion on the innertubes about whether or not this is a bug.  Looks like the provider was targeted at ASP.NET and does the right thing there.  People also disagree on where to pick up csc.exe.  I suspect this may continue to be [in flux](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/14660).

[later edit: in VS2017, csc appears to live at ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe.]

[Edit VS2022]
The API seems to have change a bit with VS2022, now I had to use the following code to set it up:

```
$pathToCodeDomProvider = 'C:\<WhereEver>\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll'
$pathToCompiler = 'C:\<WhereEver>\csc.exe'

$dncpTypes = Add-Type -LiteralPath $pathToCodeDomProvider -PassThru
$dncpTypTab = [ordered]@{}
$dncpTypes | %{$dncpTypTab[$_.Name] = $_}

$compSetCtor    = $dncpTypTab.ProviderOptions.GetConstructor(@([string],[int]))
$compSettings   = $compSetCtor.Invoke(@($pathToCompiler, 10))
$cscpOtherCtor  = $dncpTypTab.CSharpCodeProvider.GetConstructor(@([Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.IProviderOptions]))
$roslynProvider = $cscpOtherCtor.Invoke($compSettings)
```