# How to compile c#-6.0+ code at runtime?

Tags: c#, compilation, c#-6.0, runtime-compilation

I'm trying to compile a code at runtime and create an instance of one of the classes in it, but I get some errors when using c# 6+ features like string interpolation. Here is the code I'm using to compile:

```
        using (var cs = new CSharpCodeProvider())
        {
            var assembly = typeof(MyType).Assembly;
            var cp = new CompilerParameters()
            {
                GenerateInMemory = false,
                GenerateExecutable = false,
                IncludeDebugInformation = true,
            };

            if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform.ToString() != "Unix") cp.TempFiles = new TempFileCollection(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP"), true);
            else cp.TempFiles.KeepFiles = true;
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(assembly.Location);
            CompilerResults cr;

            if (Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                cr = cs.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, files);
            }
            else cr = cs.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, new string[] { path });


            if (cr.Errors.HasErrors)
                throw new Exception("Compliation failed, check your code.");


            var types = cr.CompiledAssembly.GetTypes();
            var myType = types.Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(MyType))).FirstOrDefault();
            if (myType == null)
                throw new TypeLoadException("Could not find MyType class");

            return (MyType)cr.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(myType.FullName);

        }
```

Now if I try to compile a code that uses something like:

```
string name = $"My name is {name}";
```

I get this exception: 
`Unexpected character '$'`

Comment: How do you compile this code? With which compiler version ? You need a compiler that understands and can parse the C# 6.0 syntax

Comment: Which Visual Studio version are you using? For full C# 6.0 support you need VS2015 or VS2017.

Comment: @Atesh052 I'm using VS2017.

Comment: @mjwills how can I check that?

Comment: @mjwills http://prntscr.com/fkj5bw if you can't see the picture, it says 1.0.5 and 2.2.0

Comment: Those look like the right versions. Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/40311406/34092 help?

Comment: @mjwills thanks! ill read it, i managed to solve my problem though, a stupid mistake in a "using" statement. i forgot to change the `using Microsoft.CSharp` to `using Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix to that problem was to use [Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/). And also I had to change the `using Microsoft.CSharp` to `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40311406/34092 for more info

Many thanks to @mjwillis who helped me reach this solution.