# How to force CSharpCodeProvider to compile for a specific target framework?

Tags: c#, roslyn, codedom

I've got a solution which contains c# projects, some `netstandard` 2.0 and others `.net4.7`. The startup project is of course `net47`.

At one point, the project creates code using `CodeDom` and compiles it with `CSharpCodeProvider`. The problems is that on some machines, it tries to compile the assembly for .netstandard and it fails. The failure is expected: the generated assembly references `EF` which in only available for full `.net framework`.

How can I force `CSharpCodeProvider` to compile against `.net47`?

```
public bool GenerateAssembly(
        CodeDomBusinessCode compileUnit
        , string fileName
        , string assembliesPath
        , out IEnumerable<string> errors)
    {
        var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters
        {
            GenerateExecutable = false,
            OutputAssembly = fileName,
            GenerateInMemory = false
        };
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Runtime.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Path.Combine(assembliesPath, "EntityFramework.dll"));
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Path.Combine(assembliesPath, "GlobalE.Server.Contracts.dll"));

        var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parameters, compileUnit.Code);
        if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            errors = results.Errors.OfType<CompilerError>().Select(x => x.ToString());
            return false;
        }
        errors = null;
        return true;
    }
```

The error:

```
error CS0012: The type 'System.IDisposable' is defined in an assembly
 that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 
'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
```

UPDATE:
If I change all projects to `net47` (so that there is no `netstandard` project in the solution), the error will disappear, but I want to keep as many projects on `netstandard` as possible.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, EF is definitely present: I can see it in the bin directory, and when I bring the compiled assembly from another computer (only our assembly, not its dependencies) everything starts to work. Apparently, it's only the compilation step. Updated the question to include the actual error message.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253967/how-to-target-net-4-5-with-csharpcodeprovider ?

Comment: CSharpCodeProvider is legacy, it can only target the installed version of .NET, valid options for CompilerVersion is 2.0, 3.0 or 4.0.  Your program will be compiled by C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe.  That's the legacy C# compiler, last updated in .NET 4.5, it doesn't know anything about .NETStandard.  You'll have to [bring your own](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/).

Comment: @HansPassant interestingly the answer below solved it for me. You are absolutely correct and I have no idea why adding "netstandard.dll" would work but I can confirm at least in .NET 4.7.2 that is enough to be able to work with packages targeting .NETStandard.

Answer (score 2):

based on your error, you should add "netstandard.dll" as references and it may cause by this note that in .net 4.7 the "System.IDisposable" is in "mscorlib.dll" and in .netstatndard is in "netstandard.dll".

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
var options = new Dictionary<string, string> 
              {
                  { "CompilerVersion", "v4.7" }
              };
var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(options);
```